# Insert/update contact on create of delv_user(Custom object) and link back the Contact id to delv_user

Tags: trigger, class

I have delv_user has Custom Object contains fields {delv__Contact__c(Lookup Contact),delv__Email_ID__c,delv__Phone_Number__c}. The below trigger will create the contact on insert to delv_user. The following thing need to be done.

Firstly : How to check whether the Contact isexist have Email as condition.

Secondly: How do we update field delv__contact__c on delv_user(Custom object) after create/update of contact.

Please help me solving this.

```
trigger CreatedelvuserContact on dftly_Delivery_User__c (after insert, after update) {

    if(Trigger.isInsert){

        List<Contact> ct = new List <Contact>();

        for(dftly_Delivery_User__c delvuser : trigger.new){
            Contact c = new Contact(LastName = delvuser.name,
                                    Email = delvuser.delv__Email_ID__c,
                                    MobilePhone = delvuser.delv__Phone_Number__c);
            ct.add(c);
        }
        insert ct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an after insert you can use a map to store the deftly_Delivery_User__c ID to the created contact. Then update the user object with the contact ID.

```
trigger CreatedelvuserContact on dftly_Delivery_User__c (after insert, after update) {
Map<ID,COntact> conMap = New Map<ID,Contact>();
Map<String,Contact> emails = New Map<String,contact>();

if(Trigger.isInsert){
  //Get emails in the trigger
  for(dftly_Delivery_User__c delvuser : trigger.new){
     //Probably should put a null check on email here  
     emails.put(delver.delvuser.delv__Email_ID__c,null);
  }
  //find contacts that exist with those emails and add them to the map with the contact record
  for(Contact c : [Select Email From Contact Where Email In :emails]{
      if(emails.containsKey(c.email);
         emails.put(c.email,c);
  }

    for(dftly_Delivery_User__c delvuser : trigger.new){

        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = delvuser.name,
        Email = delvuser.delv__Email_ID__c,
        MobilePhone = delvuser.delv__Phone_Number__c);
        //If the email map has the email in it and the value is not null
        //set the contact ID to the id from the map (really do not need the key check.
        if(emails.containsKey(c.email) && emails.get(c.email) != null)
             c.id = emails.get(c.email).id
        conMap.put(delvuser.id,c);
    }
    upsert conMap.values(); //upsert instead of insert

    dftly_Delivery_User__c[] tbu = New dftly_Delivery_User__c[]{};
    for(Id delId : conMap.keySet()){
        tbu.add(New dftly_Delivery_User__c(Id = delId, delv__contact__c = conMap.get(delId).id));
    }
    update tbu;
}


}
```

Keeping in mind you need to take the possibility of recursion/collision into account depending on what you do in the after update part of your trigger.

Comment: Hey Eric, Just wanted  to know, `delv__contact__c = ct.get(delId)` if we get the sobject i.e. `ct.get(delId)` and assign it to reference field ie. `delv__contact__c`. then it will work? I never tried my self. just asking

Comment: No, I forgot the `.id` part. Thanks, Updated

Comment: you're welcome. Also I have changed the `ct` to `conMap`  :-)

Comment: @Ratan - Thanks for the edits. I need to go to bed lol

Comment: @Ratan Thanks for the help. But how do i check is existing of Contact using Email. before creating the Contact.

Comment: @Chandu you can use duplicate management rule to check the duplicate emails. if email will duplicate it will simply throw an error using duplicate management rule. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29NTdMV-sM8 check this video

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the help. please help me to check whether the Contact is exist using Email r not before Insertion.

Comment: Use duplicate management as Ratan suggests or get a set of emails, query for existing contacts putting the found emails in a set and check if the email exists in the set and only create those that do not exist. You could also create an external ID field and have a WFR populate it with the email and then user upset on the new email field. - I have updated my answer, will require debugging I am sure. Kinda tired at the moment. May not be th most elegant solution either but should work

Comment: I reread your question and it seems you wanted to update existing contacts so I have modified it to do that

Comment: @Eric, Can you please help me writing test class for this above trigger